# emberjs - routing with location type 'hash' not working in tests

Tags: ember.js, ember-testing

I have routes location type set to hash, and everything works in browser, but when I try running tests it seems like ember ignores everything in the URL after the hash.

for example, the following URL works in browser:

```
/1234/#/login-enduser/
```

I see in console the following

```
Attempting URL transition to /login-enduser
ember.debug.js:27700 Preparing to transition from '' to ' login-enduser'
```

and I get to the right page.

but when I call visit() inside an ember test with the same URL, I get 404 and see this in console:

```
Attempting URL transition to /1234/
Preparing to transition from '' to ' not-found'
```

eg ember stops right before the hash (not-found is a default url I have to catch all wrong urls).

why is this happening? how do I fix it?

thanks,

Comment: Please include your router

Comment: as @Kingpin2k requested ... we need to see your router. Also is this an ember-cli app or globals? What version of ember/and ember-cli are you using?

Comment: Hi sorry for delay in replying, this was already solved - I used "visit('/login-enduser/');" with location type hash and it just works. thanks anyway :)